# Trouble viewing website outside of local network with outside IP

Tags: router, port-forwarding

Hey guys so I'm having an odd problem. I have a webserver on an adruino that i'd like to have access to outside of my home network. Accessing the HTML page hosted on there with the internal IP (10.0.0.12:2099) works fine. The external ip (24.131.79.173:2099) in the browser also works fine.  The fact that I am able to use the external IP successfully would lead me to believe it should be available outside of the local LAN?

However, when trying to access it outside of my local network, on my ATT LTE phone, it does not work.

I've forwarded port 2099 on my comcast router, put the arduino's IP in the DMZ and it still won't show up on the outside..

Comment: Not sure to understand. Is 10.0.0.12 the private ip address of your Arduino ? is 24.131.79.173 your public ip ? You have forwarded port 2099 to your comcast router, but, to me, it should be forwarded by your comcast router to the private ip of your Arduino

Comment: [image](http://i.imgur.com/WrhnPAf.png?1) 

Yeah that's what I meant to say I believe. Attached is a screenshot with my settings, are they correct?

Comment: yep, seems right. But when i run `nmap` against your public ip, port 2099 does not seem to be open. Have you setup a default gateway to your Arduino ?

Comment: i don't think so, what is that?

Comment: The default gateway is the ip address of a router able to route a host to others networks, to reach them. In your case it should be the ip address of your router. To set it up on your Arduino add this code `byte gateway[] = { 192, 168, 0, 254 };` (of course replace the ip by yours)

Comment: All I knew is the gateway was the ip of your router haha so I was able to add the gateway code to my arduino with that line you gave me, replacing it with 10.0.0.1 obviously..  but still no luck accessing it outside of my local LAN

Comment: Actually i cannot see port 2099 open, but i can see port 25,80,8080,8888 (and more). On router side, try to setup the ip/port of your Arduino the same way you have setup other services

Comment: thats what I did, but to be honest I don't think my other services were forwarded correctly either, I was just able to get them working by placing them in the DMZ.

Comment: Can you try by changing port 2099 to port 80 ? just to see if your ISP is not blocking some ports...

Comment: Yeah that's why I chose the arbitrary port 2099 to begin with, I had a feeling my ISP (Comcast) would block port 80, but I'll give it a shot once I'm back home and have access to the Arduino.  

Thanks a lot everyone!